# How to average two masks?

Tags: opencv, image-processing, scipy, computer-vision, filtering

I have two boolean masks that I got from the object detection for two video frames `i` and `i+1`. Now I want to "avarage" them to remove noise. Masks are closed convex curves. So basically I want to find the middle line between them. How can I do this?

Here is an example:
[image: Example]

Let's say that we have two maks red and blue for two successive frames, after filtering we need to get something like the green line that is between two contours.

Comment: do those curves overlap each other in successive frames?

Comment: Yes, in ~90% of surface

Comment: can you give exame images and what you want to achieve? If I understand you right, there is like some "outer contour mask" and some "inner contour mask" and you want a contour mask half the way between them? But masks aren't limited to inner/outer but can be anything?

Comment: @Micka yes, I have added image

Comment: Would something like: fill up the contours separately, get the union minus the intersection, and apply morphological operations such as Erosion or Skeletonization work? (I do not know how representative or the real example you drawing is)

Comment: _" Masks are closed convex curves. "_ they are not convex in your example

Comment: Maybe not good draw. But thay are convex. I am converting it to convex hull. With scipy

Comment: @eskapp thanks ! That makes sence. I will try

Comment: from the innermost contour-intersection area you can iterate over the contour pixels and move in gradient direction to the outside until you find the last intersection and then choose half the way or sth. But this won't work for all kind of contours (but should for convex?) but is probably ok for most.

Answer (score 2):

You can accomplish this using the [distance transform](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.2/d7/d1b/group__imgproc__misc.html#ga8a0b7fdfcb7a13dde018988ba3a43042).

The core idea is to compute the signed distance to the edge of each mask, and find the zero level set for the average. There is no need to require convex masks for this algorithm. I do assume that the inputs are solid masks (i.e. a filled contour).

The distance transform computes the (Euclidean) distance of each object pixel to the nearest background pixel. The signed distance to the edge is formed by the combination of two distance transforms: the distance transform of the object and the distance transform of the background (i.e. of the inverted mask). The latter, subtracted from the former, gives an image where pixels outside the mask have negative distances to the edge of the mask, whereas pixels inside have positive distances. The edge of the mask is given by the zero crossings.

If you compute the signed distance to the edges of the two mask images, and average them together, you will obtain zero crossings at a location exactly half-way the edges of the two masks. Simply thresholding this result gives you the averaged mask.

Note that, since we're thresholding at 0, there is no difference between the sum of the two signed distances, or their average. The sum is cheaper to compute.

Here is an example, using your color coding (red and blue are the edges of the two inputs, green is the edge of the output):

[image]

The code below is MATLAB with DIPimage, which I wrote just to show the result. Just consider it pseudo-code for you to implement with OpenCV. :)

```matlab
% inputs: mask1, mask2: binary images
d1 = dt(mask1) - dt(~mask1);   % dt is the distance transform
d2 = dt(mask2) - dt(~mask2);   % ~ is the logical negation
mask = (d1+d2) > 0;            % output
```

Comment: Looks like we even can implement some kind of the Complementary Filter for the masks flow with this  approach to reduce noise even more  newMask = a * currentMask  + (1 - a) * prevMask. How do you think?

Comment: @BransDs: yes, you can. And if you do that in a loop increasing `a` from 0 to 1, you can make a cool animation! — If you want to reduce noise, you can very simply smooth the outline by smoothing the sum of distance transforms.

Comment: @CrisLuengo this worked very well for me (implemented using cv2) in averaging the contours of carrot roots: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/fyfmb7z7842tvvj/AAC55zpka8t0L7dnXbhHvfO_a?dl=0.  One thing I don't understand is how this averaging algorithm functions at the tip (left-most point).  While the individual contours (in gray) are relatively rounded at their tips, the average contour (in red) always has this extremely pointed shape.  All the initial contours are oriented in the same direction (pointing left).

Comment: @ScottB: Interesting effect. This could be related to the distances at that point mostly being distances to the sides of the carrots rather than their tips. I don't have any other insights than that, sorry.