# Average location of two seperate binary masks

Tags: python, opencv, mask, scikit-image

I have two bianry masks such as those included below, I would like to find the average between them and create a third mask which lies in the middle. Whilst researching I found the following question [How to average two masks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51409818/how-to-average-two-masks/51414955#51414955) , however the code was matlab and I could not figure out how to recreate it in python

[image: Mask 1]

[image: Mask 2]

My current attempts are as follows:

```
current_im = cv2.imread('ENGR1.png')
new_im = cv2.imread('k9TFi.png')

middle_im = np.mean( np.array([ current_im, new_im ]), axis=0 )
_, middle_im = cv2.threshold(middle_im, 125, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
```

This returns the following image which is clearly not an average of the two, to be completely honest I have no idea why

[image]

Comment: What code do you have?  What format are the masks?  If you use PIL or OpenCV to read a numpy array, then averaging them is trivial.

Comment: Masks are PNG images, I have opened them as numpy arrays and attempted to average them and then threshold them but this doesnt seem to get the expected output. I have updated the question to reflect this

Comment: You can weight-add (blend) two images using the `acv2.ddWeight()` function. See: https://docs.opencv.org/4.7.0/d5/dc4/tutorial_adding_images.html

Comment: what's the average of "black" and "white" supposed to be? gray? then why do you threshold? that again forces each pixel to be black of white. -- you need to be able to at least _show_ what an "average" *should* look like.

Comment: @stateMachine and Christoph if you look at the other stack overflow question I referenced you will see that I am not trying to merge the two frames but instead find the intermediate mask

Comment: I'm still not clear what you expect.  Look at "blockage" at the right of the second image.  What is the "average" of that and the first image, where the blockage is clear?  If these are binary images, what is the "average" of 0 and 1?

Comment: you linked to the answer which using distance transform.
So, why your code is not include such process? why don't try it as is? (Not read only the code, read the methodology)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After lots of fiddling I managed to get it to work as I wanted with the matlab code I had included but in python as follows

```
from scipy.ndimage import distance_transform_edt
import cv2

image_1 = cv2.imread("ENGR1.png")
image_1 = cv2.cvtColor(image_1, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
image_2 = cv2.imread("k9TFi.png")
image_2 = cv2.cvtColor(image_2, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)


d1 = distance_transform_edt(image_1) - distance_transform_edt(~image_1)
d2 = distance_transform_edt(image_2) - distance_transform_edt(~image_2)
out = (d1 + d2)


_, thresh = cv2.threshold(out, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
```